# Excel identify duplicates, determine which highest priority and apply relational value to all the lower ranked duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, excel-formula

Example via google sheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-UBBgQfU4IkyxpiZNLQB0IP_pGD1H4HoDUx7h9fsX2k/edit#gid=0

I am attempting to identify servers with multiple associations and then identify which association has the highest 'priority' and therefore should then override the others as the Flag. 
I have about pulled all my hair out trying to figure this out and with over 10k line items doing it without a formula isn't viable.

I have tried using Access/Tableau Prep/VBA and Excel and I get stuck after a certain point. I converted the multiple different flags into the one Priority ranking column to hopefully make it easier but if a number value is easier that can easily be changed.

So something like:

1. look for matching Col A values,
2. when found look at Col F to determine priority (A is highest,  B is second highest and z is last)
3. if no other matching Col A shares the highest ranked priority then 'vlookup' Col G into Col H.
4. If duplicate Col A values also share the same highest ranking Col F (priority ranking) then return “Manual” in Col H.

I would love any help anyone can provide any solution in excel/vba/prep/access would be a blessing.

Comment: Hi, Lindsey. If you can send me the workbook, I'll take a look and see if I can help you.

Comment: If you can't share the workbook, create a minimal working example (MWE) and share it here. Otherwise even if somebody takes the time to create it by himself he may not get it right

Comment: @ExcelHero Thanks for your reply. I don't have excel on my personal computer and I cant send files back and forth between my work machine to make sure I do not cross any boundaries there. I made a quick basic example in google sheets with example data, please let me know if that suffices or not? If not I can download a trial excel maybe and go from there.

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos thanks for your input, I have added MWE google sheets document, due to limitations moving work files to non-work machines and my desktop not having excel. I am new here so I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula in excel cell 'H2'..

```
=IF(AND(A1<>A2,COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$14,A2,$F$1:$F$14,F2)<=1),G2,IF(A1=A2,H1,"Manual"))
```

First sort your data as shown in image below.

[image]

The your data will look like this and apply the given formula to cell H2 and copy it down.

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! That's and already really helps me but if a server shows up 4 times and 2 are As and the other 2 are G and H, it seems to be giving the A's Manual correctly but then giving the G and H ranks the asset of G instead of manual. And similarly say if 2 common servers have a G and H rank it's producing their own asset instead of applying the G asset to both.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out!